# Why are my ifelse statements not work? The "else" statement only returns NA r

Tags: r, if-statement

The "else" part of the ifelse statements is not working. Regardless of what I put in the "else" argument, it return NA.

Here is some sample data:

```
test<-structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 
2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 
2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 
2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4), nowsmoke = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), eversmoke = c(NA, 
NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, 
NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 63L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is an example an ifelse statement I have been trying to get to work:

```
test$nowsmoke<-ifelse(test$nowsmoke==TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Here is another one:

```
long_data_cancer_ceramide$smoker_4<-
ifelse(long_data_cancer_ceramide$nowsmoke==TRUE, 
     3,
     ifelse(is.na(long_data_cancer_ceramide$nowsmoke) &
       long_data_cancer_ceramide$eversmoke==TRUE,
            2,
            ifelse(is.na(long_data_cancer_ceramide$nowsmoke)&
                     is.na(long_data_cancer_ceramide$eversmoke)&
                     long_data_cancer_ceramide$time==4,
                   1,
                   NA
                   )
            )
     )
```

It seems I am able to get the first 2 parts of the statement to work (if, then). But else just always return NA. So the second ifelse statement stops working after "3,"

Comment: NA is neither TRUE nor FALSE, it's NA.

Comment: Sorry. That was a result of something I tried to make the statement work. I attempted to turn all values into true or false (as exemplified in the first example). So that was why that was there. It was originally a test condition of is.na . I have adjusted it.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `test$nowsmoke[is.na(test$nowsmoke)] <- FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-order the conditions in your `ifelse` statements, where you need to test for `is.na` first. If you first test the condition `if TRUE`, then the `NA` entries would not fit in you subsequent `ifelse`, since `NA` is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE` and therefore will not be evaluated in your `ifelse` loop.

Another suggestion: you don't need to test `if value == TRUE` if `value` are already logical, just `if value` is fine. `if !value` to test for `if value == FALSE`

```r
long_data_cancer_ceramide$smoker_4<-ifelse(is.na(long_data_cancer_ceramide$nowsmoke)&
                       is.na(long_data_cancer_ceramide$eversmoke)&
                       long_data_cancer_ceramide$time==4,
                     1,
       ifelse(is.na(long_data_cancer_ceramide$nowsmoke) &
                long_data_cancer_ceramide$eversmoke,
              2,
              ifelse(long_data_cancer_ceramide$nowsmoke, 
              3, NA)))

   time nowsmoke eversmoke smoker_4
1     1       NA        NA       NA
2     2       NA        NA       NA
3     4       NA      TRUE        2
4     1       NA        NA       NA
5     2       NA        NA       NA
6     4       NA      TRUE        2
7     1       NA        NA       NA
8     2       NA        NA       NA
9     4       NA        NA        1
10    1       NA        NA       NA
11    2       NA        NA       NA
12    4       NA      TRUE        2
13    1       NA        NA       NA
14    2       NA        NA       NA
15    4     TRUE        NA        3
16    1       NA        NA       NA
17    2       NA        NA       NA
18    4       NA        NA        1
19    1       NA        NA       NA
20    2       NA        NA       NA
21    4       NA      TRUE        2
22    1       NA        NA       NA
23    2       NA        NA       NA
24    4       NA        NA        1
25    1       NA        NA       NA
26    2       NA        NA       NA
27    4     TRUE      TRUE        3
28    1       NA        NA       NA
29    2       NA        NA       NA
30    4       NA      TRUE        2
31    1       NA        NA       NA
32    2       NA        NA       NA
33    4       NA      TRUE        2
34    1       NA        NA       NA
35    2       NA        NA       NA
36    4       NA        NA        1
37    1       NA        NA       NA
38    2       NA        NA       NA
39    4       NA      TRUE        2
40    1       NA        NA       NA
41    2       NA        NA       NA
42    4       NA        NA        1
43    1       NA        NA       NA
44    2       NA        NA       NA
45    4       NA      TRUE        2
46    1       NA        NA       NA
47    2       NA        NA       NA
48    4       NA        NA        1
49    1       NA        NA       NA
50    2       NA        NA       NA
51    4       NA      TRUE        2
52    1       NA        NA       NA
53    2       NA        NA       NA
54    4       NA      TRUE        2
55    1       NA        NA       NA
56    2       NA        NA       NA
57    4       NA        NA        1
58    1       NA        NA       NA
59    2       NA        NA       NA
60    4       NA        NA        1
61    1       NA        NA       NA
62    2       NA        NA       NA
63    4       NA      TRUE        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative coding

```
tmp=pmax(test$nowsmoke*3,test$eversmoke*2,na.rm=T)
tmp[rowSums(is.na(test[,-1]))==2 & test$time==4]=1

 [1] NA NA  2 NA NA  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  3 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  3 NA
[29] NA  2 NA NA  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA  2 NA NA
[57]  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  2
```